# Adding padding or margin to a div disables most links inside it

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

im pulling data from a db, im using while loop (php) to build a a small box with different data inside, and a button to access that id and display the rest of the information, the problem is that when i add margin or padding to the div the link href buttons become unclickable, i dont even get the hover effect, funny thing is that it does not happen to all the small divs created, the ones from the left side works, i get the hover effect and the links working fine, but the ones on the middle and right column simply doesnt work, if i remove the padding all buttons works fine but the whole items appear in a place that i dont want them, heres my code, hope you can help. THX.

HTML

```
<div class="row col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 foot">
  <div class="izq" style="margin-left:135px;">
    <div class="sombra fondoCuadro blk">
      <div class="pix esquinas"><img src='.$rows['thumbnail'].' /></div>
      <div class="tamano12 clrA ngta der">'.$rows['precio'].'</div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
      <div class="linea fA"></div>
      <div class="tamano12 clrG ngta" style="text-align:right;">'.$rows['titulo'].'</div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
      <div class="tamano11 clrG izq txt" style="margin-top:1px;">'.$rows['terreno'].' m&sup2; terreno</div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
      <div class="tamano11 clrG izq txt" style="margin-top:1px;">'.$rows['construccion'].' m&sup2; de construcción</div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
      <div><a href="detalles.php?propiedades_id='.$rows['propiedades_id'].'&&cat='.$rows['p_categoria'].'" class="btn-detalles hvr-grow pull-right">Detalles</a></div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.izq {
  float: left;
}

.outMarco {
  padding-left: 130px;
  position: relative;
  width: 73.2%;
}

.sombra {
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -3px #C5C5C5;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -3px #C5C5C5;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.fondoCuadro {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.blk {
  width: 222px;
  min-height: 270px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
}

.blk:hover {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.blk .pix {
  width: 210px;
  height: 142px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.blk .pix img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -4%;
}

.esquinas {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.new {
  background-image: url(img/new.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 53px;
  height: 22px;
}

.blk .new {
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  top: 13px;
} 

.tamano12 {
  font-size: 12px !important;
}

.tamano11 {
  font-size: 11px !important;
}

.clrG {
  color: #555555;
}

.ngta {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.clrA {
  color: #13469B;
}

.der {
  float: right;
}

.clr {
  clear: both;
  height: 1px;
}

.fA {
  background-color: #13469B;
}

.linea {
  height: 1px;  
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.blk .txt {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

Comment: give a try to http://pesticide.io ..it outlines all elements on webpage, so you can easily see what's happening.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice, im on it, just trying to figure out the color codes, in fact when i apply the padding i can see light blue squares overlapping the two rows that doesnt work and make the images behind it a little brighter, thanks again for your advice.